# How to combine paths by preserving the original path's directory separator in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, path, .net-5, path-separator

If we have `/TestDir` as an example path, yet we are on a Windows machine, using `Path.Join`, or `Path.Combine` with `NextDir` will yield `/TestDir\NextDir`.

Is there a way to make it so that if the path I'm appending it to, uses a given separator - the combined path uses the same separator? (Unix/Windows), that is:

- `\TestDir` with `NextDir` to yield `\TestDir\NextDir`.
- `/TestDir` with `NextDir` to yield `/TestDir/NextDir`.

The first directory will always be a rooted path, meaning it will always contain the path separator to use. The only edge-case is network paths, as they always start with `\\` but after that they differ in Unix/Windows? Correct me if I'm wrong on this.

**EDIT:** I've been told that `:` is the path separator for Classic Mac - is this true? I don't see any .NET API's that treat this as a directory separator.

Comment: UNC paths start with double backslash in Windows. I assume they can also start with double slash.

Comment: There's no way to do this automatically, you'd have to do your own string manipulation. But, why would you want a path with the wrong slash in the first place?

Comment: In Windows both slash and backslash is accepted, so for cross platform compatibility using forward slash can be a good idea. Make a function that will replace "wrong" slashes wherever they can be input.

Comment: @BentTranberg do you know which versions of Windows are compatible?

Comment: No, but it's been both ways for ages, so I guess any Windows version you can come across.

Answer (score 0):

This will take the first character (either `/` or `\`) that it sees and it will replace all other occurrences of `/` or `\` with the first one that it found.

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      char[] separators = { '\\', '/' };
      string path = "/TestDir\\NextDir\\AndTheNext/AndTheNext/AndTheNext\\AndTheNext";
      int index = path.IndexOfAny(separators);        
      path = path[index].ToString() == "\\" ? path.Replace('/', '\\') : path.Replace('\\', '/');
      Console.WriteLine(path);
   }
}
```

Check it out running here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fenzWO

Answer (score 0):

Path class uses a field with the name of: PathSeparator, this one depends on OS and is readonly, so that it's easier to create your own class that performs the same actions than Path but you are able to change the value of PathSeparator.

For more information about Path you may read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-5.0